# Operador condicional ternário

Tags: operadores

Estou tentando traduzir uma condição de if e else em ternário, porém as condições são compostas, ou seja, preciso indicar mais de uma instrução na mesma linha.

De acordo com o que pesquisei o mesmo pode ser executado utilizando virgula, mas no compilador ele espera que tenham mais : e ; alterei de acordo com a indicação do compilador e não resolveu, acredito ser algo simples que ainda não consegui localizar uma resposta adequada ou fragmentos de respostas que atendam e esta demanda, segue abaixo os códigos.

```
class Fibonaci{

int calculaFibonaci(int n){
            /*if(n==1){
            fibonaci=1;
            fibonaci2=0;
            } else {

                fibonaci += fibonaci2;
                fibonaci2 = fibonaci- fibonaci2;
            }

            }*/

            fibonaci = (n==1)? fibonaci=1, fibonaci2=0 : fibonaci+=fibonaci2, fibonaci2 = fibonaci - fibonaci2;


            return fibonaci;
            }
}
```

**OBS:** Dentro do comentário esta a condição `if` e `else` que funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: De curiosidade, isso é exercício? Pq na prática não faz sentido usar ternário pra isso.

Comment: Ninguém teve curiosidade de saber qual linguagem é? Tem que acrescentar a tag. Parece Java.

Comment: Sim é java é um exercício, que consiste basicamente em criar um método que faça o calculo fibonaci usando o ternário, eu fiquei em duvida mais precisamente na parte em que se fala (Expressão) ? codigo1(true) : codigo2(false), dentro do codigo acredito que seria a mesma coisa que colocaria dentro das{}, logo a duvida é posso usar mais de um comando por linah separando por virgula? quanto a tag java eu n tenho mérito ainda para colocar a tag rsrsrs

Answer (score 1):

O uso do ternário nesse caso está incorreto. O que você está tentado fazer é atribuir um valor à variável `fibonaci`. Se você quisesse atribuir um valor à essa variável, teria apenas que passar um valor único no ternário, e não criar novas atribuições:

```
fibonaci = n==1 ? 1 : 2; // fibonaci seria ou 1 ou 2
```

No seu caso, para atribuir variáveis dentro do ternário, teria que colocar o código entre parênteses, e verificando apenas se `n==1`:

```
n==1 ?
(fibonaci=1, fibonaci2=0) :
(fibonaci += fibonaci2, fibonaci2 = fibonaci - fibonaci2);
```

O ternário acima tem o mesmo efeito do `if` comentado `/**/` no código.